# Django exclude(**kwargs) help

Tags: python, django

I had a question for you, something that I can't seem to find the solution for... Basically, I have a model called Environment, and I am passing all of them to a view, and there are particular environments that I would like to exclude. Now, I know there is a exclude function on a queryset, but I can't seem to figure out how to use it for multiple options... For example, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
kwargs = {"name": "env1", "name": "env2"}
envs = Environment.objects.exclude( kwards )
```

But the only thing that it will exclude is the last "name" value in the list of kwargs. I understand why it does that now, but I still can't seem to exclude multiple objects with one command. Any help is much appreciated!

Shawn

Comment: Your title does not match your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this would be:

```
Enviroment.objects.exclude(name="env1").exclude(name="env2")
```

or

```
Enviroment.objects.exclude(Q(name="env1") | Q(name="env2"))
```

Comment: Hmmm alright then. The multiple exclude solution is the one I went with before asking the question, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution :) Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Enviroment.objects.exclude(name__in=["env1","env2"])

Comment: Interesting, I should go back and try this, maybe tomorrow at work!